# Change python version in blender

Tags: python, version, blender

Hey I think I have tried already everything to change python version in blender without success.

What I have tried:

- open with PYTHONPATH and --python-use-system-env
- remove folder python and update python in the system

Do you know some other options and can you help me?

Comment: Maybe better asked in the [blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com) community.

Comment: If you want use some python libraries of certain python version try this if on windows, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529676/can-i-import-tensorflow-and-keras-in-maya-blender/60530736#60530736.